# How to decode Apache Parquet

Tags: python, parquet

I was given a test assignment on api
I need to set up a daily data upload from the API using Google Cloud Platform.

one of the api methods /orders (date: str required) - information about payments for services by users
returns data in Parquet format, but its format is as follows
data fragment

```
��� JOۻ�� �i��������@ � ��,�����@ � [ߧ�Þ ����@ � [ߧ�Þ   ]�\   ���`@(��b�h8��dB�X.��f��x>��hD*�N��j�j�^��lF��n��n���~��pH,�Ȥr�l:�ШtJ�Z�جv�� &�5
```

here is my code with the help of which I took the data from the API

```
import requests

def get_orders_data(date):
    url = "/orders"
    headers = {}
    params = {
        "date": date
    }

    response = requests.get(url, headers=headers, params=params)

    if response.status_code == 200:
        # to see what data is transmitted because it was not written to json
        data = response.text.strip()

        return data
    else:
        print("Failed to fetch orders data")
        return None

# Calling a function with the required date parameter
date_to_fetch = "2023-12-08"  # Приклад дати
orders_info = get_orders_data(date_to_fetch)

# Processing and use of the received data (orders_info)
if orders_info:
    print(orders_info)
```

I am interested in how I can make all the data readable or at least save it to a .parquet file

I tried to do it this way

```
import io
import pyarrow.parquet as pq

# A string str with Parquet data (let's say it's called orders_info)
parquet_data_str = orders_info

# Decoding the string str to the memory buffer
buffer = io.BytesIO(parquet_data_str.encode())

# Loading Parquet data from the memory buffer
table = pq.read_table(buffer)

# Converting data to DataFrame from the Pandas library
df = table.to_pandas()

# Displaying the first few lines for verification
print(df.head())
```

but on the line `table = pq.read_table(buffer)`

the program ended with an error

Comment: Could you share the error you got with us?

Comment: Why do you `strip()` the data?

Comment: my error @kabooya
`OSError: Could not open Parquet input source '<Buffer>': Couldn't deserialize thrift: TProtocolException: Invalid data`

Comment: Why do you `strip()` the data? @tripleee

I did it, but it didn't work.

Comment: If it didn't work, probably stop doing it then? Also, the `encode()` looks quite suspicious. Probably review https://nedbatchelder.com/text/unipain.html

Comment: Not a duplicate, but try the approach from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68997995/can-i-read-parquet-from-https-octet-stream

Comment: @tripleee Thank you very much for your help, I was able to solve this problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two solutions

first

```
    if response.status_code == 200:
        # to see what data is transmitted because it was not written to json
        result = response

        df = pd.read_parquet(io.BytesIO(result.content))

        return df
    else:
        print("Failed to fetch orders data")
        return None
```

second

```
    if response.status_code == 200:
        # to see what data is transmitted because it was not written to json
        result = response

        buffer = io.BytesIO(result.content)

        # Loading Parquet data from the memory buffer
        table = pq.read_table(buffer)

        # Converting data to DataFrame from the Pandas library
        df = table.to_pandas()

        return df
    else:
        print("Failed to fetch orders data")
        return None
```

these two options work
This helped me with the decision
[Can I read parquet from HTTP(s) octet-stream?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68997995/can-i-read-parquet-from-https-octet-stream)